# JSQMessageViewController - How do I set a collection cell to be incoming or outgoing cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, outbound, inbound, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image]

Using the JSQMessage podfile for iOS, in this method;

collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
..
}

How do I set the it to use `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming` or `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing`?  I am finding it diffcult to find examples of how other apps do this

My code;

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell*)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    [cell.textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
    cell.textView.text = nil;

    VICChatMessage <JSQMessageData> *messageData = (VICChatMessage*)[collectionView.dataSource collectionView:collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textView.attributedText = messageData.attributedText;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.  It was to do with the sender details.

By default its `JSQDefaultSender` but my code was only setting it if it knew the sender; so I used a fallback for when the sender was not known.

The idea is to get the

`BOOL isOutgoingMessage = [messageSender isEqualToString:self.sender];`

inside the podfile: `JSQMessagesViewController.m`

So that it positions them either on the left or right.

In the end I had to do this in my code where I obtain my message ready for display

```
 if (message.sender.remoteID)
    {
        senderID = @"JSQDefaultSender";
    }
    else
    {
        senderID = @"sender";
    }
```

This works and solved my problem.

Many thanks all

Comment: Thenks. isOutgoingMessage delegate method works for me though it was not mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In the `messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath` method, you have to compare the sender of the message with your user. It the sender is your user, return an `outgoingMessagesBubbleImage`. If not, use a `incomingMessagesBubbleImage`

```
- (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];
    Message *message = [your_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
        return [bubbleFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor]];
    }

    return [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor]];
}
```

Comment: Will the bubbleimage actually align them left/right?  I will check out your answer.

Comment: The problem I have is that all my chats are on the left hand side of the screen.  Setting bubbles only changes the "orientation" of said bubble. Not its placement on the screen

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this, the current solution is to override the `isOutgoingMessage()` method on your `JSQMessagesViewController` and not the approved one.